# error in density.default : x must be numeric

Tags: r, error-handling

This question might have been repeated. But even after going through the previous links, I am not able to solve this. I have a file as follows:

```
data <- read.table("data.txt", header=TRUE)

             Samp1           Samp2     Samp3
cg00000029  0.79015390399987 0.8301816 0.8966661
cg00000108 0.970260858767027 0.9655997 0.9699428
cg00000109 0.948456317952246 0.9209855 0.9325146
cg00000165 0.267769194351135 0.2370634 0.3867273
```

I wish to create a density plot out of the column (say Samp1). When I use the following

```
>plot(density(na.omit(data$Samp1)), col="black")
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in density.default(na.omit(data$Samp1)) : argument 'x' must be numeric
```

Can anyone help me know how to i correct this? I have created density plots for similar files, but did not get this error. It is only for this file.

Your help appreciated.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Should you not be plotting 'data$Samp1', not 'ima$Samp1' ?

Comment: yes sorry thats my mistake which i made while typing this question. i will edit it.. so i plot 'data$Samp1'

Comment: Output from `traceback()` immediately after the error, as well as the output from `str(data)`, might be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Well, for some reason your data is non-numeric: have you tried using as.numeric() to coerce it into the right type?

**Edit**: Using unlist() to convert it out of a list type seems to be the answer

Comment: yes i did try something like "data_new <- as.numeric(data)" and i get an error "Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'"

Comment: In that case, you might need the unlist() function, which should allow you to convert out of a list object.

Comment: @RoryB.. for some reason this URL is not opening here.. Can you send the corrected URL again or tell me what to do here?

Comment: Thank you @Rory. But I just tried that. If I use something like "new <- unlist(data)", then its not keeping the exact columns. I get something like,       V11       V12       V13       V14       V15       V21       V22       V23
1.0000000 2.0000000 3.0000000 4.0000000 5.0000000 0.7901539 0.9702609 0.9484563

Or may be I am doing some mistake..

Comment: @RoryB.. I am really sorry for this confusion. The problem is still there. Do you know any other alternative ?

Comment: Can you post the error message you are getting, and the output of unlist(data$Samp1) ?

Comment: unlist(data$Samp1)
[1] 0.7901539 0.9702609 0.9484563 0.2677692 0.9027598

Comment: Can you do str(unlist(data$Samp1)) that should tell us the current type of your data?

Comment: If I do that, it gives me "num [1:5] 0.79 0.97 0.948 0.268 0.903"

Comment: Well, that should be a numeric vector, which should work. I'm afraid I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same problem, I was able to solve it by doing:

```
a<- density(treeDF$real)
plot(a$x, a$y, col="turquoise2")
b<- density(treeDF$rpart)
lines(b$x, b$y, col="deeppink3")
c<- density(treeDF$rpart_Fourier)
lines(c$x, c$y, col="blue")
legend("topright", legend = c("real value", "rpart()", "rpart() + Fourier tem"),
    col=c("turquoise2", "deeppink3", "blue"), lty=1:1, cex=0.8, box.lty = 0)
```

[image]